# Call function after finish audio file

Tags: javascript, audio

I have added one music audio player in my web application. I need to call a function after completing the audio. But the thing is audio length is not specified.

for example, 10 seconds audio finished then call a function, 7 seconds audio then call a function.

it means once audio complete then call function to event occur.
Audio length should be not specified.

here is my audio player code

```
<audio controls="controls" controlsList="nodownload" onloadeddata="var audioPlayer = this; setTimeout(function() { audioPlayer.play(); }, 4000)">
<source src="'.str_replace("\'","'", $que=$row->question).'" type="audio/mp3" id="my_audio" loop="loop"/>
</audio>
```

This is my java script code

```
setTimeout(
  function() 
  {
    console.log('10 Seconds done')
  }, 10000);
```

Here, code in message pass after 10 seconds but I need message pass after completing audio

Comment: Have a look at [Audio/Video events](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp). You will see that there are different events you can use. The event your looking for is [ended](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_ended.asp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with [`ended`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/ended_event) event. So you should only listen for `ended` event on your desired element like this:

```js
const audio = document.querySelector("audio");

audio.addEventListener('ended', (event) => {
  console.log('audio has been ended');
});
```

```html
<audio controls src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/t-rex-roar.mp3">
  Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `onended` function.

```html
<audio controls="controls" controlsList="nodownload" onended="console.log('ended!');">
  <source src="///file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3" type="audio/mp3" id="my_audio">
</audio>
```

You could also try:

```js
$('#my_audio').parent().play().then(() => {
  const checkAudio = () => {
    if ($('#my_audio').parent()[0].ended) {
      console.log('ended!');
    } else {
      setTimeout(checkAudio, 100);
    };
  };
});
```

```html
    <audio controls="controls" controlsList="nodownload">
      <source src="///file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3" type="audio/mp3" id="my_audio">
    </audio>
```